# Reset NavigationView scroll

Tags: android, drawerlayout, navigationview

simple question which I haven't been able to find an answer to or figure out by myself.

How can I have the NavigationView always start on its "original" scroll position whenever it's open, so the first menu item is always visible regardless of where the scroll position was left previously.

I've tried this without success:

```
drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
    ...

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        drawerView.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }

    ...
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well after examining the View hierarchy of the NavigationView widget, it's comprised of a NavigationMenuView that extends RecyclerView, so using this I've come up with this shenanigan:

```
((NavigationMenuView)((NavigationView)drawerView).getChildAt(0)).scrollToPosition(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the drawer items when user has selected some item in the drawer. Then

you should refresh the adapter for the listview in `onItemClick`.
call `notifydatasetchange()` to reflect the changes.
But, if you want if user has selected some item in the list, then on closing of drawer after making selection, you want to update the list, for this case you

Listen for closing of drawer event -

```
public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

// refresh adapter and call notify data set change.

}
```

See this link : https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 0):

*to rest all of items and scrolls*

I use recreate() method in *onDrawerClosed()*   or item selected like this:

```
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle
    (Navigation_view.this,drawer_layout, toolbarNavigation, 
     R.string.openDrawer,R.string.closeDrawer){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {  
         recreate();
        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);}


     nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(item ->
        {switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item1: recreate();
            break; 
             return true;
```